# Get Port of Incoming Request - App Engine, Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, port, nat

I have an application running on Google App Engine and a client connects to the server at a specific URL performing an HTTP POST (or GET or whatever) request. My question is simple: how would I go about obtaining the client's port?

Thankyou for any help anyone here can provide!

--- Additional Info ---

Note that in most cases 'Client's port' = a translated port that the Client's Modem's NAT set. If a NAT is present, I do not require the client's local port on their computer that they are using to hit the server, for this is of little use to me. Instead, I require the port from the Modem's public IP that will redirect the request to my original client.

I need this info to send more data to the client (through sockets) at some later point in time. Straight after its initial post request, the original client creates a server socket that listens for requests from the server. The server is only able to send requests to the client if it knows the ip:port of the client.

I am aware of the issue request below. It is 3.5 years old though, and still no action has been taken - it will never be fixed. I was hoping that someone here might know of a workaround.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4210&q=Type%3DDefect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&start=100

Comment: I can't imagine why you would need this, or why you think it should even be available. Why can't you use GAE's [channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) to open a persistent connection?

Comment: I described in the question as to why I need this information. Unfortunately, Chanel API isn't suitable for the per-minute rates are simply too restrictive - I can only serve one additional client per second, and if I'm really going with the whole 'scalable' idea, then this is not a good approach to build my app around.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the info on remote TCP port is not available via GAE APIs.

Most of the time clients are behind NAT so they are not accessible from internet, i.e. even if the have a listening port open, you can not Make a TCP connection to it due to one-way nature of NAT translation.

If a client has a public IP, then they can just simply tell server on which port they will be listening and you can then use URL Fetch or Outgoing Sockets to make a connection.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: if I use keep alive to keep the translation in the nat table, then wouldn't I have a way to reach the client simply by connecting through the nat's translated ip:port? I'm am most certain that NAT translation is two-ways - isn't this the way a web server replies to a client's usual requests? @para3 the issue is that the client does not have a public ip - it is the modem who has one. If any of the above is wrong please do tell me!

Comment: You can only initiate TCP connection through NAT from client side, once connection is established packets flow both way. But in your case TCP connection gets closed once HTTP request is finished, so I don't believe NAT translation would work after TCP gets closed. Also, even without NAT and if TCP was connection was still up, you still can not inject random packets across TCP connections, at least not from normal application code.

Comment: To reiterate: after HTTP request finishes, server closes TCP connection, so it can not be reused. You can try to keep it open on client side (I don't see how), but it makes no sense as server will never use it again. I suggest reading basics of TCP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: Wow, haven't been on for a long time. Too long. If you're still around, I would like to say that I did read, somewhere at least, that the definition of 'closing a TCP connection' is quite shady, and that NATs don't remove the translation from their table since they cannot be sure that it really terminated. Also, what I understood was that as long as the translation is still there, simply sending a packet to the modem's ip:port will redirect it to the pc, where there will be a socket listening and waiting for packets.

Comment: "you still can not inject random packets..." - I don't believe i am planning to. I think that a Java 'socket connection' first 'creates' the connection for me somehow and then i use an input stream/output stream to send/recieve information - so those are the packets getting sent. Wouldn't a translated nat simply forward all the information coming through, thus causing the initial 'creation request' to be sent through successfully as well? "server closes TCP connection" - I plan for the sockets to create a new TCP connection when the server pings the client at a later point in time.

Comment: Again, if you're still wandering around, would be great if you could point out any flaws in whatI wrote above. The way I see it, as long as NAT translation is not removed, this is a viable way to communicate, right? Not remove not translation = ez, use keep alive. You state the NAT is terminated when connection terminates, and that this is the issue, yet I have not been able to find any material on this - any chance you would be able to provide some? Only issue the way I see it is GAE no giving me the port to ping, and I have no clue how else to get this port! :( Thanks again for all your help

Comment: You are talking about [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). Specifically see [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) and [TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching).